# mySQL table structure with adding new users table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a small app in php using the cakePHP framework connected to mySql database.

I have two types of users (business and employees) with relationships to other tables also. I am now adding a login facility which means I will be adding a users table to hold the password details. So both employees and businesses will be able to login.

I am not sure what way to add the relationships between the users table and the businesses and employees table. I will be adding an admin role also.

My current tables are:
- course_files
- course_modules
- courses
- courses_employees
- employees
- businesses

My Choices:

1. Merge the businesses and employees table with the users and have a

   - users (id, role employee_name, business_name, business_address, etc)
   - roles (admin, employee, business)

My issue with this approach is that the fields for businesses and employees are very different so the users table will have a lot of fields. But it will make it easier for the login functionality.

2. Add business_id and employee_id to the users table. This option will be a little more involved and one field will always be blank like employee_id.

   - users (id, employee_id, business_id, role)
   - roles (admin, employee, business)
   - employees (business_id)
   - businesses

So before I go down one route and find I went in the wrong direction I was wondering what would be best practice?

Comment: You should decide what's 'primary'. In my company's database, all individuals belong to (at least) one organisation. So an individual can only be associated with a project if we've first associated that individual's organisation with that project. In some cases, those individuals are just private clients, acting in their own personal capacity, rather than through the agency of some organisation. Under these circumstances, they simply belong to an organisation called  'project_client_body'.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, what table do you store the passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with both of your approaches. I would have a users table for login, and tables for employees and business, just like you suggested in your second approach. The difference is that I wouldn't have employee_id and business_id in users because, as you've already stated, one will always be blank. Why don't you instead have a user_id in both tables, as they will always have a user profile (intended for login)? I see you use CakePHP, so these will be relationships as follows:

```
User hasOne Employee
User hasOne Business
Employee belongsTo User
Business belongsTo User
```

Let me know if any other business rules in your application make my approach hard to implement.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to me I will go in that direction